# Cannot set prompt color in iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to set the navbar prompt color in iOS11 to the same color as the navbar title color.

This works just great in iOS10:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

[image]

However this is no longer working in iOS11.  The title is white but the prompt is not.

[image]

I found a thread mentioning a hack to try and get the prompt label to change via:

```
[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]].textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

However that is not working either.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in iOS 11

Post on the Apple Developer forums:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85399

Radar issue (mirror) 34009213:

https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/18233

It seems to be reported to Apple.